# What does WSL's `--exec` option do?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With WSL 1, the output of `wsl.exe --help` includes:

> ```
> Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [CommandLine]
>
> Arguments to run Linux binaries:
>
>     If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.
>
>     --exec, -e <CommandLine>
>         Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.
> ```

Therefore, what is the difference between:

```
wsl.exe foo
```

and:

```
wsl.exe --exec foo
```

For example, I have kept my default shell as bash, but wish to use fish interactively. To achieve this, I have tried using both:

```
wsl.exe -d Ubuntu fish
```

and:

```
wsl.exe -d Ubuntu --exec fish
```

Both work fine.

I thought there might be some difference in the hierarchy of processes between the two, but running `ps` from each provides a similar result: `fish` and `ps` itself, as the only processes listed.

This leads me to the question: what is the purpose of the `--exec` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: "Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell."

Some familiarity with [`exec(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) system call in Linux kernel or with
[`CreateProcess()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) API in Windows user mode will be helpful to understand
this answer.

When `wsl.exe` is executed with only the command it is passed to the default
shell of the default WSL distribution. The shell then parses the command and
does any processing, if required (see the example). The shell process is not
appear because it (parent process) only executes the given command and terminates.

But when `wsl.exe` is executed with `--exec` or `-e` option the given command
line is not passed to any shell. It is executed as usual without any shell processing.
For example, `wsl.exe $(which ls)` works but this `wsl.exe --exec $(which ls)`
does not because `$()` is not processed by any shell.

This is true for WSL1 and WSL2 both. To verify the statement, open [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
as administrator. Add the filter "Path -- Contains -- bash -- Include". Now run
any **WSL1** distribution with and without that `--exec` option. `bash` will not
show up in later case. Here I choose WSL1 because WSL2 runs in a VM/container
and Process Monitor can not catch it.

Comment: Re: your hint, I think the line from `wsl.exe --help` which states: '*If **no command line** is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell*', is unclear, as a command line was provided and it launched the default shell. Perhaps it is intended to mean that, without a command line, the default shell will be launched so it can be used interactively.

Comment: Just because the names are similar, when you mention `exec(3)`, you mean that when **not** using `--exec` it is as though `exec(3)`/`CreateProcess()` **was** used, correct?

Comment: @JamesT I mentioned `exec(3)` as a reference. If anyone want to know how wsl.exe works internally then `exec(3)` may help.

Comment: '*The shell process is not appear because it (parent process) only executes the given command and terminates.*' This is the part that is like `exec(3)`, because, '*`exec()` . . . replaces the current process image*' (bash) '*with a new process image*' (e.g. fish)?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between the two commands

There isn't any difference if the default shell has not been changed.

> This leads me to the question: what is the purpose of the --exec option?

It allows you to run the command using the shell that is assigned within the WSL distribution.  For example, you can install Z shell, and then run a command without invoking Linux Bash Shell and instead invoke the command with Z Shell.

The explanation of the command is quite specific.  **It only requires the user to know what is considered the default shell.**

Source:

- [How to Use Zsh (or Another Shell) in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/258518/how-to-use-zsh-or-another-shell-in-windows-10/)
- [What is ZSH, and Why Should You Use It Instead of Bash?](https://www.howtogeek.com/362409/what-is-zsh-and-why-should-you-use-it-instead-of-bash/)

Comment: Much nicer answer than mine (that I am removing) @Ramhound.  I would have to add that it might also be useful of you were trying to pass a group of commands.. then the --exec part wouldn't have to come last.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I was only able to provide an answer due to your answer being submitted.  Without playing around with WSL myself (which I am not willing to do tonight), I had to extrapolate and assume some minor details (*the assumption is that the default bash shell is indeed Linux Bash*).

Comment: What do you mean by, '*the shell that is **assigned** within the WSL distribution*'?

Comment: You can have MANY distros installed (I myself have Debian and Ububtu).. @Ramhound means the default one.

Comment: @JamesT - Please limit commentary to ways I can improve the answer.  As for what I mean, you can assign any shell you want, within a WSL instance.  My answer is very specific about that, I went to great effort, to provide supporting documentation.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry if you felt I was being critical, it was not my intention, I just didn't want to put words into your mouth. What I wanted clarification on was, by the 'assigned' shell, do you mean the default shell of the distro, as in the value of the `$SHELL` environment variable?