# How to pipe data from one terminal to another under Windows with Ubuntu and WSL

Tags: windows, ubuntu, script, exec

The problem arise to provide online help to developers using an interpreter, and has been realised with Cygwin + mintty + a home grown interpreter.  So relevance and principles are well known in a Unix-like context.

But how to create a process to start a terminal, to run 'less', say, escapes me. The Unix-command 'exec' sufffices.

Provides Windows similar similar means to script commands?

Sorry for my shortcoming of knowledge of Windows.

-- Oldfux

Comment: An example to illustrate my doubts and concerns is the following console log with inserted blank lines for clarity
<pre>
jsm@DESKTOP-3KE8HUS:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$

echo "line 1
line 2" | (wsl.exe less; echo -done)

line 1
line 2
-done
</pre>
------------

The promp is followed by a simple command to send two on a pipe to be presented by 'less' and a message after termination.  But: termination is automatic and process does not run in a separate window.  So wsl.exe initiates a new bash-instance rather than runs a new process.  Can a new process only be created with clicks?

Answer (score 0):

You may start a WSL terminal by using `wsl.exe`.

The most basic command to run a single command is :

```
wsl -- command and parameters
```

The argument `--` means that everything following it is passed to the shell.

For more information see :

- The command `wsl --help`
- [What does WSL's `--exec` option do?](https://superuser.com/questions/1502482/what-does-wsls-exec-option-do)

Comment: Or, if you mean the "other way around" (as in WSL calling windows) just invoke the command using .exe as in `cmd.exe /c "dir /w"` it will hop over to the windows side, run the command and return to your bash shell. [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems) might also help.

Comment: Consider  simple and familiar application

Comment: $ cat 'file' | wsl.exe less in bash

Comment: Consider: $ cat file | wsl.exe less.  Compared to the standard interpretation in Linux (and in Unix) it differs very much from the behaviour of Ubuntu under WSL

Comment: I got sleepy and had to leave.  Back to the discussion of

Comment: My expectations are not met. The pipe may not be created or 'less' may terminate on its own. I see no second window.  Presumably the cause may hide in the system calls concerned with jobcontrol. My expectations grow in a garden of uniix-experience.

Comment: This interface is confusing me.  I expected the command $ cat 'filw' | wsl.exe less to lead to a state with two processes, the second of which with a terminal running program 'less' used to present the contents of 'file' allowing for scrolling up and down and terminates when a user type the letter q.

Comment: You will need to use a temporary file. WSL2 is implemented as a minimal Hyper-V virtual machine, so using it is not as easy.